# How to I retrieve the home directory of a user

Tags: salt-stack

let's say I have a service that has a pillar-configured user associated with it
now I want to fetch a tar.gz and put it in this user home directory...
how do I do that...

user.info return a bunch of data including the home directory.. but how do I get only that ?

iow

```
foo:
  archive:
    - extracted
    - name {{ <get the user home directory here> }}
...
```

Answer (score 9):

Trial and error got me there:

```
{% set my_user = ..get your pillar user or default to a sane value.. %}

{{ salt['user.info'](my_user).home }}
```

resolves to the user's home directory

Comment: This does not work, if the user gets created during execution.